# Artifacting on Mesh durring Movement

Tags: mesh, shaders, artifacts

Video Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDLad4J1fTM

This is a pretty high poly object with an Emission Shader in white and  Wire-frame shader in black.   Any rotation or translation of the brain results in artifact when I render, and it seems like its the Wireframe finding new edges.  Its pretty visually disturbing in animations, even from a distance.

What is the root cause of this and how can I solve it?  I've tried playing with the wire-frame size, but no dice.

EDIT:
After a computer restart its only happening when I am using the scene's camera.  Could this be a draw distance thing?  If so how do I increase the distance the camera can be before information is lost?

Answer (score 1):

An important thing in my scene was that my camera had a high focal and sensor length.  For some reason, this means I have to increase the clip start distance, because even though all geometry fell between the clip start and clip end, I guess you have to shrink the difference between the clip start and clip end to prevent... LOD errors?  Regardless, setting the clip start from .001 to 22.9 fixed the problem.